# How do I use HTML inside a JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the page, I'm not sure if it is possible with JavaScript, so I tried with HTML, and it failed.

```
if (text=="home") {'<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="1;url=index.php">'; return;}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: if you feel one answered your question, don't forget to accept it by clicking the check mark below...

Comment: Yes, I had to wait about 18 minutes or whatever it was, in that time I forgot to come back and accept it.

Do I always have to wait for these flood checks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.location.href = 'YOUR_NEW_URL';
```

Comment: you could add a setTimeout to delay it by a second as in the original example. `setTimeout('window.location.href="http://www.google.com"', 1000)`

Comment: Anurag > I copy and pasted that from another one of my scripts in my giant mess of folders. It doesn't actually need to be there, though. Thanks! (: